# even and odd proof of a polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove: Let  $x \in \mathbb{Z} $. If $x^2+x+1 $ is even, then $x$ is odd.

I tried the problem but i don't think i did it correctly

$x$ is even is $2k$

odd is $2k+1$

Substitue values: $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $

$x = 2k+1$

would i substitute $2k+1$ in the polynomial

$ 2k^2+1+2k+1+1$

$2k^2+2k+3 $

$2k^2+2k+2+1 $ = $ 2(k^2+k+1) $

Comment: I wouldn't say the definition of even and odd are $2k$ and $2k+1$, but rather all even and odd numbers can be written in those forms.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^2+x+1=x(x+1)+1$ and since the product of two consecutive integers is even (why?), this polynomial is always odd. Since the premise is false, the statement is vacuously true.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding John Hughes' detailed lesson, I can't resist pointing out that "If $x^2+x+1$ is even then $x$ is odd" is equivalent to "If $x$ is even then $x^2+x+1$ is odd." And we can verify the truth of this by observing that if $x$ is even then $x=2y$ with $y\in Z$, implying that $x^2+x+1=4y^2+2y+1=2(2y^2+y)+1 $ is odd  ( because $y\in Z\implies 2y^2+y\in Z.)$.... ...It also happens to be true that $x^2+x+1$ is odd when $x $  is odd, but that Q was not asked.

Answer (score 1):

@Foobar John's answer is completely correct, but I'm going to take your proposed answer and chew it up a little, to try to help you see how things are done in mathematics.

> Prove or disprove: Let  $x \in \mathbb{Z} $. If $x^2+x+1 $ is even,
>   then $x$ is odd.
>
> definition of even is $2k$

That's not the definition of "even". It's not even a sentence. Perhaps you should have written "$x$ is even if and only if there's an integer $k$ with $x = 2k$."

> definition of odd is $2k+1$

Same problem here.

> Substitue values: $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $

That's not a sentence either. But there's a deeper problem: you seem to be asking "what does this polynomial look like when $x$ is odd?" by plugging in $2k+1$ for $x$. But that really doesn't matter. What matters is what $x$ must look like when it's known that the value of the polynomial is odd. So you really  want to say something like

"Suppose that $x^2 + x + 1$ is even; then there's an integer $k$ with 
$$ x^2 + x + 1 = 2k."$$ (See continuation at (**) below.)

> $x = 2k+1$
>
> Ignoring that this isn't really the direction you want to go for this problem, I'm going to continue.
>
> would i substitute $2k+1$ in the polynomial
>
> $ 2k^2+1+2k+1+1$

This substitution is incorrect. When you have $x^2 + x + 1$, the first term is the square of $x$, not the sum of the squares of the terms of some decomposition of $x$. So instead of $2k^2 + 1$, you should have $(2k+1)^2$, which is $(2k+1)(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$, which is rather different.

> $2k^2+2k+3 $
>
> $2k^2+2k+2+1 $ = $ 2(k^2+k+1) $

(**) Continuing the alternative approach, I got to the point where assuming that $x^2 + x + 1$ is even yielded an integer $k$ with 
$$
x^2 + x + 1= 2k
$$
That means that
$$
x^2 + x = 2k - 1
$$
Factoring, we get
$$
x(x+1) = 2k-1
$$
As @Foobar observes, $x(x+1)$ is the product of two consecutive integers, so one of them must be even, so the product is even. The right-hand side, however, is $1$ less than an even integer, hence is odd. So the two sides cannot be equal, and the original assumption that $x^2 + x + 1$ is even must be false.